# Help with Pressure, Winds, Precipitation and Climate Zone

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, climate, geography

So I've decided to re-do my worlds winds with a more realistic approach. Honestly the entire process has overwhelmed me, so I need some help with certain things.

This is the climate map map by itself.
Key:

Dark Blue = Tropical rainforests

Blue = Savannah

Red = Hot Desert

Orange = Hot Steppe

Pink = Cold Desert

Cream = Cold Steppe

Light Green = Eastern Maritime

Green = Western Maritime

Light Blue = Laurentian
[image]

This is the pressure, wind and precipitation map for the equivalent of January on my planet.
[image]

Yellow is seasonal high pressure, green is seasonal low pressure. Dark blue is either ITCZ or polar front, depending on latitude. Red is subtropical high zone. Blue is what I think is wet.

This is for the equivalent of July.
[image]

You should also know that my planet orbits a star with 0.68 solar masses. Its orbit is ~178 days long, and its effective temperature is 20 degrees. Its atmospheric pressure at sea level is 1.3 atm. Its radius is 1.25 Earth radii.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Okay, so I’m pretty sure this means my pressure zones/winds are alright. Now I just need help filling in the last bits and pieces of the climate map. Also, does it look right?

EDIT 2: Sorry it took so long to get this done, I was caught up with life. Anyway, here is a grid to represent longitudes and latitudes. Each square up/down and left/right is 15 degrees, hopefully...

Oh and also, the Equator is 6 lines up from the bottom line.

[image]

Comment: I have a strange feeling I am missing some important information. The first sentence seems to indicate that you have posted a question before, but I have no way of finding that question. Whenever you post, you have to remember that the vast majority of people on this site have no idea who you are.

Comment: We need a better view of the topology of the mountain - height, shape, size. Methinks it woul act much like an airplane wing in terms of air pressure of the winds blowing past it. and this would determine rainfall, but this is difficult to tell. Also, the size of the island itself  is important.  Is it continent sized or island sized? How big are your climate zones? My back yard has 'climate zones', but not as deliniated as yours.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I should have mentioned, this is the entire world map, so this is a supercontinent/Pangea. The highest part of the mountain is around 7000 meters.

Comment: So very conceivable that the mounain would act as an air foil, low pressure on the south side, rain on the lee side  of the winds. The winds would probably not go over the mountain, but around it. There would be wind vortexes behind the mountain. Looks conceptually possible, very plausible. Good work.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Alright, but would that mean there would be a high pressure zone on the leeward side of the mountain and a low pressure zone on the windward side?

Comment: Depends onthe angles and the exact direction of the wind. There could possiblybe a 'atall' scenario. See https://www.mpoweruk.com/flight_theory.htm

Comment: Could you show where your equatorial, tropical, and polar lattitudes are?   Also what do the various lines in the oceans represent?  Ocean currents? Wind directions?

Comment: @hszmv The lines in the oceans represent what are hopefully correct ocean currents. Again, sorry I couldn't respond sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the youtube channel Artifexian have some videos on this topic, he also deals with a more hyper realistic worldbuilding that you might be interest.

[How To Design Realistic Climates 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lCbxMZJ4zA)
[How To Design Realistic Climates 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fag48Nh8PXE)
[Hot & Cold Planet Climates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnKUbcVrZVg)
[Terrestrial, Waterworld & Tidally Locked Planets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_E9UShtyY8)
[Climate Zones Of RETROGRADE Planets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNfrYrIl9o8)
[Wind, Weather, and Mordor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LifRswfCxFU)